# How can I get the hex color values for text in a VS Code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

I'm trying to do an oversimplified presentation about java to a person who doesn't know anything about programming. I would like to know what Hex color values are exactly used in Visual Studio Code, so I can write the code from inside the presentation itself.

These are the colors closest to those of vscode that I have set so far:

[image]

It would also be nice to have some more vivid versions of these colors for a presentation, if you know better hex color codes for this.

Comment: don't use smart quotes for strings

Comment: if you need to add a `"` to a string use `'` string terminators, or even template strings with back ticks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the colour code of whatever text the caret is on by using the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

You can also read a specific theme's json file. If it's a theme extension you installed, find the extension in the `.vscode/extensions` folder in your user home directory, then find the theme file path and open that file. Ex. [package.json for VS Code's builtin Solarized Dark theme](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/theme-solarized-dark/package.json) and [its theme JSON file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/theme-solarized-dark/themes/solarized-dark-color-theme.json).